# PHP: как одномерный массив преобразовать в двумерный?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив вида:

```
Array (
  [ФРУКТЫ] => Array()
  [0] => Яблоки
  [1] => Груши
  [2] => Бананы
  [3] => Апельсины
  [4] => Сливы
  [ОВОЩИ] => Array()
  [5] => Лук
  [6] => Помидоры
  [7] => Огурцы
  [8] => Картофель
  [ЗЕЛЕНЬ] => Array()
  [9] => Укроп
  [10] => Петрушка
  [11] => Кинза
)
```

Какой есть оптимальный способ преобразовать его в двумерный массив вида:

```
Array (
  [ФРУКТЫ] => Array(
    [0] => Яблоки
    [1] => Груши
    [2] => Бананы
    [3] => Апельсины
    [4] => Сливы
  )
  [ОВОЩИ] => Array(
    [5] => Лук
    [6] => Помидоры
    [7] => Огурцы
    [8] => Картофель
  )
  [ЗЕЛЕНЬ] => Array(
    [9] => Укроп
    [10] => Петрушка
    [11] => Кинза
  )
)
```

Возможно, имеются какие-то специальные php-функции для подобного преобразования?

Comment: самый оптимальный - сразу получать в нужном виде. откуда берется массив?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение вашего велосипеда по описанию ответа Ипатьева:

```
$array = [
    'Фрукты' => [], 'Яблоки', 'Груши', 'Бананы', 'Апельсины', 'Сливы',
    'Овощи' => [], 'Лук', 'Помидоры', 'Огурцы', 'Картофель',
    'Зелень' => [], 'Укроп', 'Петрушка', 'Кинза'
];

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    is_array($value) ? $so = $key : $new[$so][] = $value;

print_r($new);
```

Comment: тот случай, когда тернарный оператор не к месту

Comment: @teran, почему? красиво, лаконично и, главное, работает!

Comment: Кратко, лаконично и с двухкратным первышением по памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, никаких специальных php-функций нет.
Чтобы преобразовать массив, требуются обсолютно не специальные функции, цикл: 1 шт, условный переход: 1 шт.

Перебираем массив в цикле, получая ключ и значение в переменные используя foreach
проверяем тип значения
если это массив - присваиваем значение из ключа в особую переменную.
иначе добавляем в новый массив новый элемент, используя особую переменную и текущий ключ в качестве ключей двумерного массива.